# Implement a key listener in java console application

Tags: java, console-application, keylistener

I'm trying to implement a simple program(with a forever loop) in java which is terminated when user press 'a' key.I can do it using system.in but user should press Enter key after pressing 'a'.I want the program to be terminated just after pressing 'a'.Is there any way to do it.I found that use of JNI is a solution but I dont prefer using third party libraries because this is just a simple code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I dont prefer using third party libraries because this is just a simple code.

Then it can't be done.

A standard Java console can not respond to single key presses, period, and so all solutions will require a third party or JNI/JNA or non-console (gui) solution.

Comment: Thanks Hovercraft Full Of Eels,is there any code which I can implement this using JNI library?.It'll be a great help.

Comment: @HeshithaHettihewa: I myself have not used JNI for this. I have used a small AutoIt application tied to a Java application by sockets for similar problems, although this solution is limited to Windows machines only. There are also 3rd party consoles available that may allow this to work.

Comment: Ok thanks i'll do some research on third party libraries which can help.

Answer (score 1):

I coped with this issue a couple of years ago, or maybe even more. I found out a trick that worked for me in a Ubuntu system. The trick is to call

```
stty -icanon min 1
```

before executing the application; this same trick is used as part of the library [jline](http://jline.sourceforge.net/apidocs/jline/ConsoleReader.html#readVirtualKey) which has been used for the windows environment.

Comment: Thanks FabioDch.Is there any way to do it in windows environment?.

Comment: No, sorry ... maybe you could try creating an hidden JFrame, or something like it, and listening for some keyEvent ... but it's nothing more than an hack. As Hovercraft's said "A standard Java console can not respond to single key presses".

Comment: Ok I understand now.I'll try using a library.Thanks for the replies.